# How to extract a field with space in JSON

Tags: json, automated-tests, extract

How i extract a value of field "Test with Space" on this JSON.
Usually i use $[0].testDTO.keywordsTest, but this field have a space in name and i dont know to make.

```
[{  
        "testDTO": {
            "keywordsTest": [
                "test1"
            ],
            "keywordsTestTwo": [
                "test2"
            ],
            "Test with Space": 45.0
        }
}]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use bracket notation:

```js
$[0].testDTO["Test with Space"]
```

More about it here: https://medium.com/dailyjs/dot-notation-vs-bracket-notation-eedea5fa8572

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can use bracket notation, see here:

```
var test = {
    "id": "109",
    "No. of interfaces": "4"
}
alert(test["No. of interfaces"]);
```